# Google Map Mobile App (share markers public)

Tags: javascript, api, codeigniter, mobile

I'm new developing mobile apps, and I want to create a google map App where people can save their own location and be able everyone to see it. The idea is share skills in the local area, so people download the app, pin themselves down on their specific location and people surrounded the same post code can see it?

Is this possible? any valuable help? please!!

Many thanks!

I have this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.710,-73.994), //New york, NY
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions)
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Of course, it is possible.
Create a database that keeps the information of users such as their name, location, and skills. When a user wants to share her/his location, upload it to your database. When a person logs in to the app, fetch those locations and skills. Then, show it in your map.

Comment: Thanks Burak! Really really helpful! Do you know any way, site, etc to create this data base?

Comment: In software, there are 2 different things: Frontend (android, ios, web) and Backend (database, server etc). First, decide which language you will use to communicate with the client. That would be NodeJS for example. Then, decide which database you will use. That can be PostgreSQL. Then, decide where to deploy your backend code. That can be Heroku. They are actually the keywords that I can provide you. From that point on, you should search for those words and try to make an application.